# Почему не работают базы данных, которые создавались на MySQL от другого Open Server'а?

Tags: mysql, openserver

Я скачал все базы данных на внешний жесткий диск (папка OS Panel/userdata/MySQL-5.7-x64). Прихожу на работу. Кладу их в соответствующую папку на рабочем ПК. Захожу в PhpMyAdmin - базы есть. Но хочу открыть какую-либо таблицу какой-либо базы - выдается ошибка, что таблица не существует.

Запускаю сайт - то же самое, летят исключения, что таблица не существует. Почему так? Версии PHP, Apache, MySQL те же самые, что и на другом OpenServer'е.

Comment: потому-что необходимо выгружать базы данных через phpMyAdmin - export (экспорт), а не копировать файлы и вставлять их на другом сервере. Делаете экспорт полной базы данных и полученный файл импортируете на другом хостинге.

Comment: *Почему так?* Потому что они не зарегистрированы. См. документацию по подключению при выполнении Raw copy при переносе данных для репликации.

Comment: @Akina, я удалил прошлую версию OpenServer. И что теперь делать? Эти БД уже никак не восстановить?

Comment: @Akina, я восстановил базы данных. Значит, их нельзя просто копировать на съемный жесткий диск? Неужели постоянно на работе нужно делать export, а по  приходу домой - import? Неужели нельзя хранить их на внешнем жестком диске - как и домены Open Server?

Comment: Можно - формально. Но обратное включение их в работу должно обставляться определёнными, достаточно неудобными, телодвижениями. Посему таким способом никто не пользуется.

Comment: @Akina, а вы можете сказать или дать ссылку, где подробно написано (желательно на русском), какие именно нужны действия, чтобы включить в работу базы? Может, я напишу bat'ник, который за меня все это будет делать.

Comment: На русском - нет. И батником тут не отделаться (то есть можно, наверное, но монстр будет ещё тот, и стопудово он где-то накосячит). Официальную документацию нужно начинать, вероятно, с [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Copying Tablespaces to Another Instance](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tablespace-copying.html).